# Problem with showing data (Batch GPS Importer)

Tags: qgis, mapping

I'm trying to show all my tracks from the last years in one map. Works excellent, except one year. After using Batch GPS Importer for this particular year 2021, I can only see a small part of a lot of imported tracks. An example (using Batch GPS Importer):

[image]

You can see just a little, small orange line. When I add this track as a detached layer, I see this on my map:

[image]

Showing the whole track with all the tracking points!

So my question: how is it possible that I only see a small part of my track when I add all the tracks in one batch, while I can see the whole track when I add the tracks one by one?

There are hundreds of tracks in this year, my map symbol/cartographic symbol will 'explode' if I add these tracks one by one. Regardless of all the time, it needs to add them this way.